# Problem with installing a python module

Tags: python, pip

Hi I am unable to download a python module dm.smlsec.binding 1.0b3. The following error is what I get. I have attached my log file please help me sorting out

```
------------------------------------------------------------
/usr/local/bin/pip run on Thu Jul 18 12:23:36 2013
Downloading/unpacking dm.xmlsec.binding
Running setup.py egg_info for package dm.xmlsec.binding
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-student/dm.xmlsec.binding/setup.py", line 199, in <module>
    **setupArgs
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 112, in setup
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 260, in __init__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 284, in fetch_build_eggs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 569, in resolve
    dist = best.get(req.key)
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (lxml 2.3.2 (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('lxml>=3.0'))
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-student/dm.xmlsec.binding/setup.py", line 199, in <module>
    **setupArgs
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 112, in setup
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 260, in __init__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 284, in fetch_build_eggs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 569, in resolve
    dist = best.get(req.key)
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (lxml 2.3.2 (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('lxml>=3.0'))
----------------------------------------

Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-student/dm.xmlsec.binding

Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 139, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 266, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1057, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 236, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/pip/util.py", line 662, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-student/dm.xmlsec.binding
```

Comment: Oh you mean https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dm.xmlsec.binding ?

Answer (score 2):

#### Use `pip`

Install the Python package manager: [python-pip [image: Install python-pip]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/python-pip).

To install the latest stable version run

```
sudo pip install dm.xmlsec.binding
```

or if you need a specific version:

```
sudo pip install dm.xmlsec.binding==1.0b3
```

This method using `pip` is preferred over `easy_install` or `setup.py`, because it can keep track of dependencies and updates, much like `apt` on Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you so much !! I sorted it out and I would follow the method using pip for my further installation of packages.

Comment: @user176056 If this answer fixed your problem, I recommend [accepting it](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the gray check mark to the left of it.